# <form:input> inside of <form:select> How to realize?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm building a jsp which will let user select data from database, it will uploads when page will render for user. But the problem is `<form:select>` don't let user insert new value his own one if the value not represented  in the list(doesn't inputed in database).

I need let user put his own value if it's doesn't not exist in the `<form:select>`.

It's kinda has to be `<form:input>` with `<form:select><form:options items="myList"></form:select>`.

Could you help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can provide textbox and dropdown.Make textbox enable only if user didnt select any value from dropdown allow him to enter value. If he selected any value from dropdown make the textbox disable.for this you should use bit of jquery or javascript.

Comment: oh. I gon't know about java script anything. could you help me with some article to read. Thank you

Comment: You can see plenty of jquery and javascript resources for beginners. Just google it.